# How accurate is the user locale on Android?

Tags: android, locale

I want to detect certain local/culture related properties for the users of our App, mainly to display/hide certain payment methods and to preselect currencies.

How accurate are the country and currencies that `Locale.getDefault()` returns on Android?

What sources of information flow into that, are things like the SIM carrier involved?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `Locale.getDefault()` depends on the language you select in Settings->Language & Input->Language Setting only. If you switch it, the `Locale.getDefault()` switches, too!

Comment: Yep, I'm more interested in the _country_ though. As far as I know, on iOS the country is obtained from the credit card when the users activate their devices. I thought that maybe on Android this is done via Google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The default locale is usually set depending on the users language settings in the android settings. Therefor, you cant rely on it and be 100% sure that the user is actually were he pretends to be.

A god method to deal with payment options and that would be to let the user select a locale at first start of your app and store the information n shared prefs. You can then use that locale for your application.